# Incorrect inbox message

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, comment-replies

For comment in [c programming - printing sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749414/c-programming-printing-sentences?noredirect=1#comment42083269_26749414) , Rizier123 mentioned the question poster @tim.
But I received the notification in my inbox due to the fact that my display name has "tim" as prefix.

My understanding is that when there are multiple participants with the same username prefix specified in a comment, the *current behavior* is to notify the most recent one.

However, when there is indeed a participant whose username *perfectly matches* the specified name, matching the most recent one instead of the perfectly matched one is counter-intuitive. Could the current behavior be changed?

Comment: @JanDvorak But "tim" is not my username. Although it's 3 characters, there is a better match.

Comment: From the linked thread, "Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John."  Matches are based on three or more characters, your name matches `@tim'.

Comment: So if one name is a prefix of another name, it's never possible to specifically address the person with the shorter name? That does seem odd. It would make more sense to me if an exact match wins over a non-exact match, independent of the order.

Comment: The thing is that when you try to add a comment on that question and you type "@t", the names "tim" and "timrau" pop up.  So if you select "tim", the notification still goes to "timrau"?  That's not who you selected, so that's definitely a bug.

Comment: @timrau Looks like if this situation occurs again, they'll have to visit another one of tim's questions  (where no one else with a username beginning with "tim" has participated) and leave him a comment about the other question.  An ugly workaround, but they aren't going to fix this bug.

Comment: @pacoverflow In this particular case, the comment author shouldn't have included the `@tim` because the owner of the post always gets notified.  Usually the @OP would get stripped out, but the system was confused by timrau's comment and thought it was addressed to him (since in some cases, you really don't want to type out a long username).

Comment: @Troyen That's another thing I don't like.  Given that the system gives you a pop-up with choices once you start typing "@t", there's no reason for the system to have this username shortening feature.  The pop-up already gives you convenience, so I think they should just require exact usernames to avoid other issues like what the OP mentioned.